# Linking to file on internal network share

Tags: macos, mac

Is there a way to create a direct link to a file on an internal network share on Mac OS X.
In windows you can do this with file://filepath, but I can't find a solution that works on Mac

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It works great for me when using `file:///path/to/file` . Note the three slashes, two for the file "protocol" and one as part of the path.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear exactly what it is you want to do.  You say, "local network share", but the example you give suggests a link to a local filesystem, rather than a network share (and Karl's answer demonstrates this latter functionality).

I believe it is possible to link to a network share in windows, with a URL such as:

```
file:////servername/share/
```

That's "file://" + "//servername/share/").

You can accomplish the same thing on OS X using an smb: URL.  For example, the link equivalent to the previous example would be:

```
  smb://servername/share
```

Clicking on this in Safari does exactly what you would expect (connects to the network share and opens a window in the Finder).